# AngularJS localstorage for a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a newbie to IonicFrameWork and was following their "starter tab" template and made a few modifications to "delete" and "bookmark" items from a factory.

My `books.js` which contains the factory looks as follow:

```
.factory('Books', function() {

  // books data
  var books = [{
    id: 0,
    title: 'Sample Title',
    author: 'Sample Author',
    category: 'Horor, Fiction',
    cover: '/cover.jpeg',
    details: 'some details about the book',
    chapters: [
      {
        id : 1,
        name: 'Chapter 1',
        filename: 'chapter1.html',
      },
      {
        id : 2,
        name: 'Chapter 2',
        filename: 'Chapter2.html',
      }
    ]
  }
  .....  
  return {
    all: function() {
      return books;
    },
    // remove a book from the list
    remove: function(book) {
      books.splice(books.indexOf(book), 1);
    },
```

and my `controllers.js` looks like this:

```
....
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, Books) {

  $scope.books = Books.all();
  $scope.remove = function(book) {
    Books.remove(book);
  };
})
.controller('singlebookCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Books){
  $scope.book = Books.get($stateParams.bookId);
  $scope.toggleIcon = function ($evemt, iconName, book){
  var buttonClasses = $event.currentTarget.className;
  // add the book to favorite
  if (....){
      book.isFavorite = true;
  }
  // remove the book from favorite 
  else {
      book.isFavorite = false;
  }
  ....
```

when I exit the app and open it again, the deleted item is back and favorite items are gone.

When searching for a solution , I came across [this article](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/) which states I should use `window.localstorage`. But not sure how I should apply this method for a factory.

Answer (score 2):

I personnaly prefer using [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) that makes it very simple and straight forward to use `localStorage & sessionStorage`.

For example, after injecting the dependency in your controller  you can:

**Set a variable :**

```
$scope.favList = [1, 4, ...]
$scope.jsonList = { ... }
$localStorage.favLists = $scope.favList;
$localStorage.jsonList = $scope.jsonList;
```

**Access a variable, Simply access to localStorage value :**

```
var favList = $localStorage.favLists;
```

Answer (score 0):

For all intents and purposes you can treat Local Storage just as if it were a key/value store, like a javascript object. So if you want to save a value in local storage, just do it like the following.

```
window.localStorage["bookOne"] = "STRING HERE"
```

Or if you want to save a javascript object:

```
window.localStorage["bookOne"] = JSON.stringify({a:b})
```

And it should persist between page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue here is that in your code, you are setting `books` on each load with `var books = ...`. Every time you reload the application it will re-apply `books` and favourites will be lost. So beyond just saving it to `window.localStorage` you will also have to read from local storage and assign it to your `books` and `favourites` variables when your app loads in order to see the changes that were previously made.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it with [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) module, here's some example based on your problem.

```
angular.module('app', ['LocalStorageModule'])
  .factory('Books', function(localStorageService) {
    // favorites list(books id)
    var favList = [1, 2, 3, ...];
    // ....
    return {
      remove: function(id) {
        favList.splice(favList.indexOf(id), 1);
        // sync with localStorage
        localStorageService.set(favorites, favList);
      },
      // ....
    }
  });
```

**Note** that you can simply use [angular-local-storage#bind](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage#bind) and bind specific scope-key to this service that automatically do this synchronisation for you. for example:

```
// Inside your controller
$scope.favList = [1, 4, ...]
// returns a deregistration function for this listener.
$scope.unbind = localStorageService.bind($scope, 'favList');
```